# Problem Restoring iPad (iOS 5.1.1)

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm having trouble restoring my iPad running iOS 5.1.1. I forgot my passcode and tried restoring the iPad but it ran out of power, since then it has failed to power on.

Answer (score 1):

Take it to a Genius Bar and see if they can help. There's not much else to be said.